# Uniform affecting shader flow and performances

Tags: c++, c, opengl

i was experimenting with OpenGL fragment shaders by doing a huge blur (300*300) done in two passes, one horizontal, one vertical.

I noticed that passing the direction as a uniform (vec2) is about 10 time slower than to directly write it in the code (140 to 12 fps).

ie:

```
vec2 dir = vec2(0, 1) / textureSize(tex, 0);
int size = 150;
for(int i = -size; i != size; ++i) {
    float w = // compute weight here...
    acc += w * texture(tex, + coord + vec2(i) * dir);
}
```

appear to be faster than:

```
uniform vec2 dir;
/*
  ...
*/
int size = 150;
for(int i = -size; i != size; ++i) {
    float w = // compute weight here...
    acc += w * texture(tex, + coord + vec2(i) * dir);
}
```

Creating two programs with different uniforms doesn't change anything.

Does anyone know why there is such a huge difference and why doesn't the driver see that "inlining" dir might be much faster ?

EDIT : Taking size as a uniform also have an impact, but not as much as dir.

If you are interested in seeing what it looks like (FRAPS provides the fps counter):

- [uniform blur.](http://puu.sh/h2F2I/e3feb404d3.jpg)
- ["inline" blur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GK7IX.jpg)
- [no blur.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0GXP.png)

Quick notes : i am running on a nVidia 760M GTX using OpenGL 4.2 and glsl 420. Also puush's jpeg is responsible for the colors in the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good guess would be that the [UBOs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) are stored in shared memory, but might require an occasional round-trip to global memory (vram), while the non-uniform version stores that little piece of data in registers or constant memory.

However, since the [OpenGL standard](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec42.core.20120427.pdf) does not dictate where your data is stored, you would have to look at a profiler, and try to gain better understanding of how NVIDIA's GL implementation works.

I'd recommend, you start by profiling, using [NVIDIA PerfKit](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-perfkit) or [NVIDIA NSIGHT for VS](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition). Even if you think, it's too much trouble for now. If you want to write high-performance code, you should start getting used to the process. You will see how easy it gets eventually.

EDIT:

So why is it so much slower? Because in this case, one failed optimization (data not in registers) can cause other (if not most other) optimizations to also fail. And, coincidentally, optimizations are absolutely necessary for GPU code to run fast.

Comment: So you are suggesting to try `uniform vec2 dirUni; vec2 dir = dirUni;` ?

Comment: You can try out many things (and you should). However, even if this "works" wiith OpenGL 4.2 on a 760M GTX, it might show very different performance on a different card and/or a different OpenGL version. Not to mention, a different driver.

Comment: uniform vec2 dirUni; vec2 dir = dirUni; does not change anything but taking size as an uniform does have an impact but it is only about 50%.

Comment: Have you tried making `size` const? What about changing it from `int` to `float`? [Might be faster](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/716194/integer-performance-vs-floating-point/).

Comment: I am currently looking into PerfKit (as i am not using VS nor eclipse). How can a so small (8 bytes) thing have such an impact ? There are only two drawcalls.

Comment: It's called a [data dependency](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070526232947AApF0id). The processor has to wait for data to arrive before it can process it. That is the very very simple explanation. In reality, there might be many many more complicated factors involved. For example, the loading from the UBO might stall the `texture` call because it goes through the same memory unit but with incompatible address modes (so they cannot be batched together). There are many other possible scenarios. Modern computers are miraculous things.

Comment: const or float don't change anything. I see why it might be slower, i am however still clueless as why i would be ten times slower.

Comment: Because as a result of one optimization failing (data not in registers), other (if not most) optimizations also fail.